# Laravel 4: protecting routes provided by a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a Laravel 4 app and I want to protect my admin area so it is only accessible if the user is logged in/authenticated.

What is the best way to do this?

The Laravel docs say you can protect a route like this:

```
Route::get('profile', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
// Only authenticated users may enter...
}));
```

But what happens when my route looks like this:

```
Route::resource('cms', 'PostsController');
```

How do I protect a route that is directing to a controller?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [Route Groups](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups) for this purpose.

So for example:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('profile', function()
    {
        // Has Auth Filter
    });

    Route::resource('cms', 'PostsController');

    // You can use Route::resource togehter with 
    // direct routes to the Resource Controller
    // so e.g. Route::post('cms', 'PostsController@save');
});
```

Comment: Hi guys, this was an easy to implement answer - though I only needed: 

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('cms', 'PostsController');
});

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can put the filter on the constructor of your Controller like this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth');

        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));

        $this->afterFilter('log', array('only' =>
                            array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PostsController you can put a closure in the constructor to do the same before logic as the previous route.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter(function()
        {
            //
        });
    }
```