# 'auth' Middleware with Route::resource

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, middleware

How can I use middleware with resources?

```
Route::resource('myitem', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'App\\Controllers\\MyitemsController']);
```

Just followed https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/struggling-with-routeresource-and-auth-middleware but unfortunately could not solve.

Getting error:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Array to string conversion
Open: /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

protected function getResourceAction($resource, $controller, $method, $options)
{
    $name = $this->getResourceName($resource, $method, $options);

    return array('as' => $name, 'uses' => $controller.'@'.$method);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4 or 5? Because the tag says 4 but middleware is something introduced in Laravel 5...

Comment: Im using laravel 4. Are you sure that its a feature in laravel5?

Comment: Really useful question. I've just started Laravel 5 and the documentation is not always clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using filter with resource was not working that why had to use `Route::group`

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('myitem', 'App\\Controllers\\MyitemsController');
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512478/540144

Comment: I think this is closer to the best answer. I was unable to get a Route:resource working with the Controller as the second argument followed by an array. Putting all my protected routes into a group worked.

Answer (score 3):

Middleware is a new feature of Laravel 5. In Laravel 4, **filters** where something similar. So instead of using the key `middleware` you should use `before` or `after`. Also, and that's where the error comes from, the second argument of `Route::resource` should be the controller name as string and the third one is an array of options:

```
Route::resource('myitem', 'App\\Controllers\\MyitemsController', ['before' => 'auth']);
```

### Edit

Apparently before filters only work with resource routes when you wrap a group around it. See the OPs answer for an example...

Comment: I see. Fromt his time have to search explicitly with laravel 4 as laravel 5 is public now.

Comment: Sorry, i had to use Route::group

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan I agree. Using Route:group was the only solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up against this and found the easiest way is to add the middleware straight to the controller.

I found my answer here:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers

```
class MyitemsController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Instantiate a new MyitemsController instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do this in **Laravel 5**. The Answer you have been waiting for.

Use `middleware` instead of `before`

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController',
                    ['only' => ['edit']]);
}
```

To check if the route is setup, run:

`php artisan route:list`

which should show the following:

`GET|HEAD  | user/{user}/edit | user.edit | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit  | auth`

Note `auth` instead of `guest`

Answer (score 0):

Better solution

Use middleware instead of before

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
   Route::resource('myitem', 'MyitemsController');
});
```

You can check if it's ok with:

php artisan route:list